# Strange Problem with MGTwitterEngine for ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, mgtwitterengine

I am stuck with the strange problem of MGTwitterEngine for iPad because when I use it for iPhone it works perfectly but when I use it for iPad then in method below(delegate method) I am getting username as null but in iPhone it was giving correct(eg.soha00)

Code for calling MGTwitterEngine:-

```
-(IBAction)loginWithTwitterButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
  {
      _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self];
      _engine.consumerKey = @"PzkZj9g57ah2bcB58mD4Q";
      _engine.consumerSecret = @"OvogWpara8xybjMUDGcLklOeZSF12xnYHLE37rel2g";

      UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine: _engine delegate: self];

      if (controller) 
      {
          [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
      }

  }
```

The below method is the delegate method that gets called when authorize button is clicked.

```
- (void) OAuthTwitterController: (SA_OAuthTwitterController *) controller authenticatedWithUsername: (NSString *) username {

    NSLog(@"Authenticated with user %@", username);
}
```

**In iPhone it is showing username properly but on iPad it is returning nil.**

Please suggest me what might be the problem or how could I sort this issue.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see the source code of these classes is available on the Internet.  Have you thought about running the code in the debugger to see where the username actually comes from?

Comment: no I dont know about that.I will see it.

Comment: @JeremyP please help me if you know something on from where did username comes from.

Comment: Sorry, I was only suggesting to do what I would do as a first step.  I'd debug the application to understand where the user name comes from.